# innerHTML in for loop not appending elements correctly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append data from an object in a table through `innerHTML` in a `for` loop but it doesn't append it in the table; instead appends the data after the table

Here's my code:

```js
var data = { "video": false,
             "vote_average": 8.300000000000001,
             "vote_count": 9363}

var collection = Object.entries(data);
// console.log(document.domain); 
var showData = document.getElementById('showData');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ExecuteMe);

function ExecuteMe(){
  showData.innerHTML += '<table class="table table-inverse">'+
                        '<thead><tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  
  feedData();
}

function feedData(){
  for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
    showData.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' +
        collection[i][0] + '</td><td>' + collection[i][1] +' </td></tr>'; 
  } 
  showData.innerHTML += '</tbody></table>';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="showData"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Why is it not appending the data in separate rows?

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't append, it overrides everything inside it. Notice, that `+=` is just a shortcut to `.innerHTML = .innerHTML + something`, it is not an append operator.

Comment: But I have appended it with +=

Comment: LOL, we just had another question with same issue.... :) innerHTML is NOT building a string. Build a string and THAN add it to the innerHTML....

Answer (score 3):

When you assign a value to `innerHTML`, it is parsed as HTML and converted into DOM.

This performs error recovery and inserts things like the missing `</table>`

When you read from it, the DOM is converted into HTML (and will include all the normalisation and error correction).

`+=`, remember, reads from it to get a string, modifies the string, then assigns the new string back. It doesn't "append" except in the abstract sense.

---

If you want to append stuff: **do not use innerHTML**.

Use `createElement`, `appendChild` and so on.

Comment: Using a string variable to assemble the HTML code first, and then assigning the content of that variable to the innerHTML property of the target element in one go at the very end would also work here.